# Поиск запроса в json и привязка к сессии

Tags: php, json

Всем привет, есть необходимость хранить данные сотрудников в json в формате:

```js
{
   "login": "IUSergeev",
   "located": "Москва",
   "Full": "Сергеев Иван Юрьевич",
   "Group": "ГР 2",
}
```

Сотрудник при входе вводит логин (в данном случае IUSergeev), нужно найти его логин в json и
вывести данные в виде массива, при этом привязать все данные к сессии, чтобы в последствии более не нужно было производить поиск.

Подскажите как это можно осуществить?

Comment: JSON находится в файле или это тип хранения данных в БД?

Comment: В файле, БД в данном проекте по объективным причинам нельзя юзать..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для прочтения файла нужно применить метод `file_get_contents()`, который вернет строку. Эту строку надо преобразовать в массив с помощью `json_decode()`. После чего уже можно сделать поиск в этом массиве по ключу через `array_search()` или другим методом. Соответственно, привязка к сессии через `$_SESSION[KEY] = VALUE`.

Чтобы больше не проверять файл надо сделать проверку сессии после ее запуска: `if (array_key_exists(KEY, $_SESSION)) {...}`.

Попробуйте набросать решение по предложенной схеме, а если что-то не будет получаться, то напишите в комментариях.

Comment: array_search не ищет по ключу, и не подойдет для поиска в этом массиве. я рекомендую в таких случаях предлагать foreach